# How do I call a javascript file that's embedded in a dll in my asp.net web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, embedded-resource

In a library I am building for my asp.net, is it possible to embed a javascript file as an embedded resource and still be able to retrieve it via a URL call and/or script tag without creating a secondary ashx just to load the javascript?

Answer (score 5):

It's entirely possible.

A quick google came up with this really good tutorial [Managing Your JavaScript Library in ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/196727/Managing-Your-JavaScript-Library-in-ASP-NET)