# Convert Angular JavaScript file into DLL file in ASP.NET MVC Project

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm embedding a JavaScript file as a resource in an assembly. How can I convert Angular JavaScript file into DLL file in ASP.NET MVC project?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I call a javascript file that's embedded in a dll in my asp.net web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13608388/how-do-i-call-a-javascript-file-thats-embedded-in-a-dll-in-my-asp-net-web-appli)

Comment: I think you didn't get my point. Your suggestion is to call a javascript file on the other hand my purpose to to create DLL of AngularJs.

Comment: What would be the end usage of your intended approach ? As I read though the answer of the question https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/196727/Managing-Your-JavaScript-Library-in-ASP-NET. He embeds the JS into the Assembly, later refers to them and invoke the functions. Isn't that isn't you intended ?

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio, righ click on the file name -> Go to Properties (Advanced Section). Select Build Action "Embedded Resources'.

Comment: But I could not find 'Embedded Resources' in Visual Studio 2015